# stanford corenlp, splitting sentences, abbreviation exceptions

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there an option in Stanford Corenlp for specifying abbreviations?
For example in the sentence: `The reason pt. stayed at home was to rest.` pt is the abbreviation for patient and corenlp incorrectly splits it into two sentences.

I was wondering how can I pass the list of abbreviations to the Stanford's tokenizer.

Comment: Are you looking specifically at clinical/medical language? If so, then don't use Stanford corenlp. Switch to a toolkit specializing in biomedical NLP. Fair warning, though, it's a horrendously difficult domain for NLP.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no, there's no way to specify custom abbreviations currently" (as far as I know). The longer answer is that this code lives in a `*.flex` file, and you could add custom abbreviations to it. I think the place to do so is in [PTBLexer.flex](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex#L641) under the ABBREV1 definition.

Comment: I changed the file and recompiled, but it didn't work.
I added my abbreviations to ABBREV1 in line 641.

Comment: Should the .flex file be compiled differently?

Comment: Yes, you'll likely need to compile that with jflex.