# How can I teach the NLP Splitter

Tags: stanford-nlp

Please give me directions:
How can I "teach" the splitter to split such paragraph:
**The paper is 7 cm. length. What is the painter name? the size of the picture is 5 cm. x 8 cm.**
into 3 parts.
and not to 5 parts as done by default:
**1) The paper is 7 cm.
2) length.
3) What is the painter name?
4) the size of the picture is 5 cm.
5) x 8 cm.**
Thanks, Aryeh.

Answer (score 1):

The tokenizer is entirely rule-based so you can add custom abbreviations to it. You will have to edit [PTBLexer.flex](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex) and recompile it using [JFlex](http://jflex.de/).

See also "[stanford corenlp, splitting sentences, abbreviation exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334991/stanford-corenlp-splitting-sentences-abbreviation-exceptions)".