# What is the default behavior of Stanford NLP's WordsToSentencesAnnotator when splitting a text into sentences?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Looking at [WordToSentenceProcessor.java](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/WordToSentenceProcessor.java), `DEFAULT_BOUNDARY_REGEX = "\\.|[!?]+";` led me to think that the text would get split into sentences based on `.`, `!` and `?`.

However, if I pass the string `D R E L I N. Okay.` as input, e.g. using the command line interface:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP 
             -annotators tokenize,ssplit  -file test.txt
```

It returns just one sentence `D R E L I N. Okay.` instead of  two sentences `['D R E L I N.',  'Okay.']`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does split on these characters, however only when they appear as their own token and not at the end of an abbreviation such as in "etc.". So the issue here is not the sentence splitter but the tokenizer which thinks that "N." is an abbreviation and therefore does not split "N." into two separate tokens. If you know in advance that your text doesn't contain any abbreviations the easiest thing to do is to split all tokens that contain a period at the end before you process them with CoreNLP.

Your input would then be `D R E L I N . Okay .`

In case your input also contains abbreviations, things are a bit more complicated as you'll have to edit the rules of the tokenizer. See "[stanford corenlp, splitting sentences, abbreviation exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334991/stanford-corenlp-splitting-sentences-abbreviation-exceptions)" for a high-level description on how to edit the rules of the tokenizer.